# Invert values in a numpy slice

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an array of zeroes and ones. When I get a slice how could I invert the values?

Here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((10,10))

x1,x2 = (4,4)
y1,y2 = (6,6)

# set some ones
a[x1:y1,x2:y2] = 1

# get a slice or view
v = a[x1:y1,x2:y2]

# invert values
v = 1-v

# somehow the values assigned in the 'v' don't appear in 'a'?
print(a)
```

Comment: That assignment creates a new memory space. Use `v[:] = 1-v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up from Divakar comment, you can use [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) built-in fuction to check that the two `v` variables are different, and [numpy.may_share_memory](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html) to check if and when `a` and `v` share memory:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((10,10))
x1,x2 = (4,4)
y1,y2 = (6,6)

a[x1:y1,x2:y2] = 1

v = a[x1:y1,x2:y2]
print(id(v), np.may_share_memory(a,v))
#259977568 True

v = 1-v
print(id(v), np.may_share_memory(a,v))
# 259979728 False
```

While by modifying the existing `v` as suggested will yeild:

```py
v = a[x1:y1,x2:y2]
print(id(v), np.may_share_memory(a,v))
# 259978968 True

v[:] = 1-v
print(id(v), np.may_share_memory(a,v))
# 259978968 True
```